# Can't get serial output while using Ethernet

Tags: serial-port, arduino, ethernet

I started to experimenting with the Arduino Ethernet [shield](http://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoShields) and got it working with not much effort. However, when I try to debug through the hardware serial port of the board, I get nothing, and though the program still runs, and I know it should be giving me something, it doesn't. Truth be told, I haven't got a clue of what's going on. How do I fix this problem?

P.S. I am using one of the example sketches included in the Arduino IDE.

Comment: Can you give us a link to the example sketch you are using?

Comment: I am using the code under examples/Ethernet/WebServer. But this is something I've noticed happening to any code using the ehternet class, either as server or client.

Answer (score 0):

The Ethernet shield does not use the RX and TX pins (0,1) and I have personally used Serial communication with the shield before.

So it definitely had to do with your code. Can you post your code?

Also have you connected anything to digital pins 0 and 1?

Comment: I don't know why, but it seems like I made a mistake, it is actually an Arduino ehternet, that for my understanding is just like a regular arduino Uno with the ethernet interface incorporated.

Answer (score 0):

The Arduino Ethernet board is not equivalent to Arduino Uno + Etherent shield. In the Arduino Ethernet board the USB-to-serial chip is not present.

From the official [Arduino Ethernet board page](http://arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoBoardEthernet)

> The Ethernet differs from other boards in that it does not have an
>   onboard USB-to-serial driver chip, but has a Wiznet Ethernet
>   interface.

So I don't think you can print any values in the serial monitor.

**Update**:

You need an external FTDI adapter like http://arduino.cc/en/Main/USBSerial get the serial communication between Arduino and your computer to work.

Comment: Well, I've got the FTDI adapter, and for other scketches I can get serial output. I've only got trouble when I use the ethernet library and the board is plugged in the ehternet.

Comment: What version of Arduino IDE you are using? Also in which OS?

Comment: I am using arduino 1.0.1 under windows XP SP3.